# Simulate pasting a value into a field using React (2/ redux-form)

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Looking for some tips on what I could do to achieve this. Basically, I have an input with buttons near it for quick entry. When the buttons are clicked, it needs to simulate pasting a value into the text field where the user's cursor is located. Also if there is something highlighted it should replace it with the text entered.

I am using redux-form's change action to update the value right now, which works for adding onto the end - but does not give the effect I am looking for.

Comment: use the state function in redux

Comment: @KARTHISRV not sure what you mean exactly, is there something in the state I can use already? Or are you suggesting storing data in the state to determine this

Comment: you can store the data in the state

Comment: Can you please elaborate it Forum - https://gitter.im/reactjs/redux

Comment: @TroyCosentino Not sure what your implementation looks like but is it possible for you to set refs (functional) on those inputs and do you have access to the rendered DOM nodes in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve here goes against how the browser behaves by default. Clicking on a button will cause an input to lose its focused state along with the cursor position. You can get around this, of course, by overloading your component state but as you add more inputs and logic it might become too much to manage.

For the sake of argument, I'm posting one possible solution here, it's not something I'd ship to production unless there was a very good reason for it.

You'll need to store the input value in state, this is what [redux-form](/questions/tagged/redux-form) does, I'm using plain component state in my example. Whenever your focus moves from the input to the button (blur event) you get the input `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` and make a state update replacing what's between them in the original input value with your custom value.

Like I said, adding multiple inputs to the mix will complicate matters as you'll need to tie each input ref to a state key.

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return <form>
      <input 
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        ref={e => this.input = e} 
        onBlur={this.onBlurInput}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
      />
      <br />
      <button 
        ref={e => this.button = e} 
        type="button" 
        onClick={this.onAppend}
      >
        Append to cursor
      </button>
    </form>;
  }
  
  onBlurInput = (e) => {
    // `e.target` is the input being blurred here
    const stringToInsert = 'Hello World';
    const {inputValue} = this.state;
    const {selectionStart, selectionEnd} = e.target;
    
    // We've clicked the button and the input has become blurred
    if (e.relatedTarget === this.button) {
      const newInputValue = inputValue.substring(0, selectionStart) + 
                            stringToInsert + 
                            inputValue.substring(selectionEnd);
      
      this.setState({
        inputValue: newInputValue
      })
    }
  }
  
  onAppend = (e) => {
    // Re-focus the input
    this.input.focus();
  }
  
  onInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That makes a ton of sense, I was not aware of the `selectedStart` and `selectedEnd`. Will give you the bounty, one question - this is how you would approach something like Slack's chat box where it guesses what you are typing? Not letting me add a gif of what I mean..

Comment: Do you mean the autocomple that shows up when you start typing in an emoji name, like :smile... or the one for user names / channel names #fronten... ?

Comment: Yes exactly! Although now that I think about it theres may only work with adding onto the end

Comment: Yep, I think that's what Slack does as well but only when you're selecting stuff with the mouse. They also have event listeners on that input for keyboard navigation and stuff.